# Class to the immediate child is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code to call the class. Its work in some browsers. but in some other browsers it will not work. i need to give as a immediate class. then only its working in all browsers. Is any other solution for that?

code is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="abc">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Immediate child<td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In Above code class abc is not apply to immediate child text in all browsers. but the following code is working in all browsers.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td >
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="abc">Immediate child<td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a bulk of files to change that. Please tell me is there any other solutions for that?

All css property will not work. If i put the class abc to the immediate td means its work. my question is why the css is not working when i apply it for outside of table?

Comment: Please show the related CSS for the class, as well as describe what "will not work" means.

Comment: @rfornal All css property will not work. If i put the class abc to the immediate td means its work. my question is why the css is not working when i apply it for outside of table?

Comment: Please go read [ask], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: OK,we cannot tell you what the CSS is doing in either example without seeing the code for the class `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont close the tags correctly, the last two `<td>` should be `</td>`

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="abc">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Immediate child</td>
          <!--CHANGED FROM <td>Immediate child<td>-->
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td><!--CHANGED FROM <td>-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I doubt that is the actual issue here. More likely there’s a problem with styles being overwritten by rules targeting the table or tr elements in between.

Comment: Ok, you are probably right (lets wait for the css :)). Thought that unclosed tags might mess it up for some browsers.

Comment: @CBroe All css property will not work. If i put the class abc to the immediate td means its work. my question is why the css is not working when i apply it for outside of table?